# php curl a instagram devuelve resultado extraño

Tags: php, curl, instagram

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php'); 

    $usuario = "username";
    $password = "password";

    $url = 'https://www.instagram.com/';
    $url_login = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/';
    $user_agent = array("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 ",
                  "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36");

    $ch = curl_init(); 

    $headers = [
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'Content-Length: 0',
    'Host: www.instagram.com',
    'Origin: https://www.instagram.com',
    'Referer: https://www.instagram.com/',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36', 
    'X-Instagram-AJAX: 1',
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'  
    ];

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie/pruebalogininsta2.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $sTarget);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);

    $html = curl_exec($ch);

    preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $html, $matches);
    $cookies = array();
    foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
        parse_str($item, $cookie);
        $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
    }


    $headers = [
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    //'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
    'Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'Content-Length: 0',
    'Host: www.instagram.com',
    'Origin: https://www.instagram.com',
    'Referer: https://www.instagram.com/',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36', 
    'X-Instagram-AJAX: 1',
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'
    ];

    $cadena_agregar_vector = 'X-CSRFToken:'. $cookies["csrftoken"];

    $headers[] = $cadena_agregar_vector ;

    $sPost =  "username=".$usuario . "&password=". $password ;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sPost);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_login);  

    $html2 = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.instagram.com/");  

    $html4 = curl_exec($ch);

    echo $html4;
```

Este es el resultado que me devuelve[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El comentario que agregaron y borraron tenia la respuesta, gracias. Es agregarle la codificacion UTF-8

Comment: Lo borre porque creía que venia de otro problema... al menos te ha solucionado :)

Comment: En realidad me acaban de explicar en otro lado que esa linea funciona porque anula otra linea.. y que la respuesta optima seria sacar la linea 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' . De cualquier forma, problema solucionado!

Comment: Me alegro de todas formas... responde te tu mismo por si alguien le surge el mismo problema... saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré la solución, estaba en sacar:

```
'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate'
```

del array `$headers`.